# prevent duplicate entries mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Hello guys I have a problem with a script

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$dbname = 'site';
  $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$con)
    {
    die(mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$sql = "REPLACE INTO stiri (id, titlu, continut, link, categorie, data) VALUES   ('','$titlu','$text','$link','Liga 1','$data')"; 
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($con);
```

This part is in a php foreach part and every time I run the script I get duplicate entry, how can I prevent this?
I could use UNIQUE Constraint but I want the link to be unique which is longer than 125 chars..

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated mysql_ functions if you can help it. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: You shouldn't put all of that in a `for` loop. Creating and closing connections like that is unnecessary.  Just create the connection, and put the statements you want to run in the `for` loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database  =>i think this link will help you.....

Comment: @AnkurSaxena i've seen that post, but i need the link to be unique wich is longer than 125 chars, is that a problem ? the server will run slower or..

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `id` is a primary key field in your table? You're trying to insert an empty string (`''`) into it. If that's an INT field, mysql will convert `''` into 0. After the first such insert, you'll run into the duplicate key problem.

Change `id` to be an auto_increment field, and insert a `null` value, e.g.

```
REPLACE INTO stiri (id, ...) VALUES (null, ....)
```

so mysql can generate an ID for you automatically.