# MySql How to prevent duplicate entry into database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to avoid duplicate entry into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database)

this  is my query to add the user and denying them if there already exists an user with the same name in the user table:

```
insert into  user values(?, ?, ?, ? ) select * from user 
where NOT EXISTS(select * from user where user.username = ?);
```

Comment: you didnt see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database

Comment: @Sudhir That is what close votes are for.

Comment: same name or same username ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `INSERT IGNORE`. If there is a duplicate in a unique column, nothing happens.

Comment: @downvoter Could you please leave a comment explaining what I got wrong? That way I can fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i guess you mean same username because names can be same .

so try use this and see

```
     INSERT INTO  user (column1, column2, column3,...)
     VALUES  (value1, value2, value3,...)
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT username FROM user)
```

if you mean name , just replace name by username

Answer (score 0):

Why don't define username as primary key if it should be unique?