# Add two indexes to the same field in MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-key

I have a table like this:
**something**
a [INT]
b [INT]
c [INT]
...where *a*, *b* and *c* are separate **Foreign Keys** pointing to three different *table.id*. Since I want to make all regs be unique, and after having read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219858), I think I should create a new Index this way: `UNIQUE INDEX(a, b, c)` and (in my case) do IGNORE INSERTS.
But as you can see, I would have one KEY for each column and then another extra UNIQUE INDEX containing all three. Is this a normal thing? It seems strange to me, and I have never seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal and reasonable to include a column in more than one index. However, if the combination of (a, b, c) is enough to uniquely identify a row it seems that you want a `PRIMARY` index instead of a `UNIQUE` one here (technically there is very little difference, but semantically it might be the better choice).

Comment: Thank you. Here is a great answer too for those who don't know the differences between PRIMARY and UNIQUE (http://stackoverflow.com/a/708508). Going to accept your answer in some minutes ;D

Answer (score -1):

Creating a Primary Key if Something (a, b, c) will invalidate the need for a unique index. An additional Unique index would make sense if your primary key was Something(a, b) and you wanted a Unique Index (a, b, c). But since all three columns are Foreignkey then a Primary key index is what you.