# Insert into only if it doesn't exists

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, insert

**Hello folks!**

We're working on a multithreading application.

We need to insert information into a MySQL database, ONLY if it hasn't been inserted before.

The current SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO core_links SET scan_id = '$scan->id', address = '$link_new'
```

There's more than 600 records inserted per second, and I would like to avoid using a select query before. Any possible solution?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) is what you are looking for.

`INSERT IGNORE INTO core_links SET scan_id = '$scan->id', address = '$link_new'`

Comment: Yeah, I messed up (searching on Google for 'insert ignore mysql' gave me the 5.5). However, I would suggest updating your answer to linking to the page you just commented with; the page you link to doesn't reference `INSERT IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

If the table's primary key is a composite of scan_id and address (or maybe only scan_id), then the table itself will reject duplicate values.