# mysql don't post dupes to table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database with a table of movies with their respective directors.
I have a form where one can add a director to a movie, but I want to not add duplicates (i.e. someone adds a director to a movie that is already in the movie director table.

I have the following, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why this still adds the duplicate:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $movie_id = $_POST[movie];
    $director_id = $_POST[director];
    echo $movie_id;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $director_id;
    echo '<br/>';


    $add_sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO MovieDirector (mid, did)
                VALUES ($movie_id, $director_id)";

    if (mysql_query($add_sql, $db_connection)){
        echo "added director to movie ";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "Failed "; 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to avoid duplicate entry into mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about what the `IGNORE` modifier keyword does for `INSERT` statements in MySQL. The role of `IGNORE` is not to prevent duplicate records from happening, but to make errors silent.

So, there are multiple ways you could go about this:

1. you could modify your schema to not allow duplicate records and either continue to use the `IGNORE` keyword, or better yet, handle theerrors

   `ALTER TABLE MovieDirector ADD UNIQUE INDEX(mid, did);`
2. you could also modify your query to not insert a record if one already exists

   ```
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MovieDirector WHERE mid = $movieId AND did = $directorId)
   INSERT INTO MovieDirector (mid, did) VALUES ($movieId, $directorId)
   ```

You probably want both of the above (probably minus the `IGNORE` keyword.. that's just going to come and bite you later)

This answer would be incomplete if I did not stress that you should really be using parametrized queries instead of adding the variables directly into the query string!

Comment: This answer would also be incomplete if we did not stress to STOP. USING. `mysql_*`!!!! It's been deprecated for some time, and outright removed in PHP7. Seriously, there's a [giant red message](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) explaining this in the documentation.