# Check if SQL entry exists before adding to database from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Values from the array `$sql` are being added to the database `$safe_id`. `$sql` gets its values from the array `$list` which contains crawled dynamic title and price information from a website. Here is some example data from `$list`:

```
[0]=> array(2) {
    ["title"]=> string(53) "Axe Heaven Miniatuur gitaar | Vintage Sunburst Finish"
    ["price"]=> string(10) "€ 31,50"}
[1]=> array(2) {
    ["title"]=> string(59) "Axe Heaven Miniatuur gitaar | Neil Young Vintage Distressed"
    ["price"]=> string(10) "€ 31,50" }
```

Adding to the database works. However, every time the script is run all data is added without a check for duplicates, resulting in a lot of duplicate entries. I'm trying to check if the data exists in the table with the variable `$exists`. The goal is to only add the data to the table when it does not exist. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
 $sql = array();

 foreach($list as $row) {

   $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['title']);
   $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price']);

     $exists = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title FROM $safe_id WHERE title = '$title'");
     $doesexists = $exists->fetch_object()->title;

       if(!$doesexists) {
         $sql[] = '("'.$title.'" , "'.$price.'")';
       }
 }

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $safe_id (title, price) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: how about adding unique keys to stop dupes

Comment: Try adding unique key  reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to avoid duplicate entry into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary/unique key in the DB and use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) OR `INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE` syntax:

1. In phpmyadmin create a unique index on column `title`
2. In your php script, use the query that updates the existing record with a new price or just ignore the Insert statement completely

Comment: phpmyadmin is not required

Comment: I agree completely. But easiest to do when not being an 'experienced' mysql user.