# Prepared Statements to check that Follower isn't already Following Followee?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I need to check MySQL database to see if a follower is already following a followee. But I'm not sure how to do it. I'm guessing I should be using IF statements. Here's what I've managed so far;

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
include 'pdo.php';

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$currentuserid = $_POST['currentuserid'];

$checkexist = "SELECT follower, followee FROM follow WHERE followee = :userid";
$checkvalues = [':userid' => $userid];

$query = "INSERT INTO follow (followee, follower) VALUES(:followee, :follower)";
$values = [':followee' => $userid, ':follower' => $currentuserid];

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($checkexist);
    $stmt->execute($checkvalues);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row->followee != $currentuserid) {
            if ($row->follower != $userid) {
                $res = $pdo->prepare($query);
                $res->execute($values);
                echo "Successfully followed user";
            }
        } else {
            echo "You can't follow yourself";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error following user';
    die();
}
```

What I'm really trying to do is;

First, check that the follower isn't trying to follow themselves (the followee).

Then check that the follower isn't already following the followee.

Finally to insert a record with the follower following the followee.

Comment: You can just compare `$userid` and `$currentuserid` for the first one, surely? As for checking whether they're already following, change the table to make the combination of follower / followee unique and when you try to insert the new row, it'll refuse to do so and you can trap the error.

Comment: Wow I didn't know you could do that! How do I change the table to make the combination unique?

Comment: Use UNIQUE key constraint in your table design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to avoid duplicate entry into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database)

Comment: That worked! I constrained the table, removed the first query entirely, and simply used $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO follow (followee, follower) VALUES(:followee, :follower)";  Now is there any way I can check if the INSERT did IGNORE so that I can echo a message telling the user they already followed?

Comment: Specifying IGNORE means that you don't want it to return an error because of a constraint - if you do want to trap an error, don't specify IGNORE.